# how to play more than one wav file in c#.net

Tags: c#, naudio

I need to play more than one wav file simultaneously (at same time). It must have option for volume control and stop, pause, and play.

I am using naudio dll for this. it works fine but some times application goes crash.

This is my code:

```
_WavOut = new WaveOut();
_WavReader = new WaveFileReader(soundfilepath);
_WavReader = (WaveFileReader)WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(
    _WavReader);
_WavOut.Init(_WavReader);
_WavOut.Play();
```

This is the stack trace I get:

at NAudio.Wave.WaveOutBuffer.WriteToWaveOut()
at NAudio.Wave.WaveOutBuffer.OnDone()
at NAudio.Wave.WaveOut.Callback(IntPtr, WaveMessage, IntPtr, NAudio.Wave.WaveHeader, IntPtr)

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: _WavOut = new WaveOut();
 _WavReader = new WaveFileReader(soundfilepath);
  _WavReader = (WaveFileReader)WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(_WavReader);
  _WavOut.Init(_WavReader);
   _WavOut.Play();

Comment: i am using naudio dll for this. it works fine but some times application goes crash , when i see the event logs , then i found following details:-Stack: at NAudio.Wave.WaveOutBuffer.WriteToWaveOut() at NAudio.Wave.WaveOutBuffer.OnDone() at NAudio.Wave.WaveOut.Callback(IntPtr, WaveMessage, IntPtr, NAudio.Wave.WaveHeader, IntPtr)

Comment: it  gives option for volume control too by using       _wavout.volume=50;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**now i am using wmp.dll.. which works great.  create an object of windowsmediaplayer object and give them  playingurl, then it will play and also be able to play more than multiple wav file simultaneously by creating the more than one object and also have mute option in obj.setting.mute=true; and also have stop play and resume option by using obj.controlls.stop functionality.**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SoundPlayer, this is impossible.

Comment: i am using naudio dll for this. it works fine but some times application goes crash , when i see the event logs , then i found following details:-Stack:
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveOutBuffer.WriteToWaveOut()
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveOutBuffer.OnDone()
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveOut.Callback(IntPtr, WaveMessage, IntPtr, NAudio.Wave.WaveHeader, IntPtr)